# how to get unique values in all columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to list out all the unique values in all columns in a Pandas dataframe and store them in another data frame. I have tried this but its appending row wise and I want it column wise. How do I do that?

```
raw_data = {'student_name': ['Miller', 'Miller', 'Ali', 'Miller'], 
        'test_score': [76, 75,74,76]}
      df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['student_name', 'test_score'])


      newDF = pd.DataFrame() 

      for column in df2.columns[0:]:
          dat = df2[column].drop_duplicates()
          df3 = pd.DataFrame(dat)
          newDF = newDF.append(df3)

print(newDF)


Expected Output:
student_name  test_score
Ali          74
Miller       75
             76
```

Comment: Expected output? I'm guessing `df2.stack().unique()`

Comment: I have updated my question with some duplicates and expected output. thanks

Comment: `df2 = df2.drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you can use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

If want check some column(s) and keep first rows if dupe:

```
newDF = df2.drop_duplicates('student_name')
print(newDF)
   student_name  test_score
0        Miller        76.0
1      Jacobson        88.0
2           Ali        84.0
3        Milner        67.0
4         Cooze        53.0
5         Jacon        96.0
6        Ryaner        64.0
7          Sone        91.0
8         Sloan        77.0
9         Piger        73.0
10        Riani        52.0
```

And thank you, @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ for another solution:

```
df2[~df2.student_name.duplicated()]
```

---

But if want check all columns together for dupes, keep first rows:

```
newDF = df2.drop_duplicates()
print(newDF)
   student_name  test_score
0        Miller        76.0
1      Jacobson        88.0
2           Ali        84.0
3        Milner        67.0
4         Cooze        53.0
5         Jacon        96.0
6        Ryaner        64.0
7          Sone        91.0
8         Sloan        77.0
9         Piger        73.0
10        Riani        52.0
11          Ali         NaN
```

EDIT by new sample - remove duplicates and sort by both columns:

```
newDF = df2.drop_duplicates().sort_values(['student_name', 'test_score'])
print(newDF)
  student_name  test_score
2          Ali          74
1       Miller          75
0       Miller          76
```

EDIT1: If want replace dupes by first column by `NaN`s:

```
newDF = df2.drop_duplicates().sort_values(['student_name', 'test_score'])
newDF['student_name'] = newDF['student_name'].mask(newDF['student_name'].duplicated())
print(newDF)
  student_name  test_score
2          Ali          74
1       Miller          75
0          NaN          76
```

EDIT2: More general solution:

```
newDF = df2.sort_values(df2.columns.tolist())
           .reset_index(drop=True)‌
           ​.apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates())
```

Comment: Or just `df2[~df2.student_name.duplicated()]`?

Comment: This is not giving the desired output i have updated my question with desired output could you please look in to that. Thanks

Comment: @KumarAK - please check last edit, I think the best is `df2.drop_duplicates().sort_values(['student_name', 'test_score'])`

Comment: by using this its still giving duplicates in student_name.  student_name  test_score
2          Ali          74
1       Miller          75
0       Miller          76

Comment: If want not duplicates in first column, you need replace them by `NaN`s, solution in `EDIT1`.

Comment: thanks i got it..but here the problem is i dont want to keep the column names static it should be dynamic.

Comment: Can you explain more? Do you want check dupes in column by position - e.g. check dupes in first and second column only?

Comment: check dupes in all columns in the dataframe not with columnname like(studentname etc).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163170/discussion-between-kumar-ak-and-jezrael).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here's the answer. newDF = df2.sort_values(df2.columns.tolist()).reset_index(drop=True).apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates()) 
print(newDF)